# jqGrid row ordering by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any option for jqGrid row ordering by drag and drop ? I would like to save the order in DB. I have checked all existing solutions relatedto jqGrid drag & drop. But, nothing is working properly.

Comment: which jqGrid you refer to? this http://www.trirand.com/blog/ or this  http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with `ASP.NET MVC`. But you should know that this easy to implement only if you don't have pager.

The main idea is to get all ids in your grid after drop and change `item_order` in your **DB**.

**HTML**

```
<table id="jqgTopMenu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="jqgpTopMenu" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$('#jqgTopMenu').jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("TopMenus")',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Id', 'ItemOrder', 'Name', 'Short name'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true },
                { name: 'ItemOrder', index: 'ItemOrder', hidden: true },
                { name: 'PostName', index: 'PostName', align: 'left', width: 430 },
                { name: 'PostNameShort', index: 'PostNameShort', align: 'left', width: 500 },
    ],
});
//sort Part
$('#jqgTopMenu').jqGrid('sortableRows',
{
    update: function (e, ui) {
        var ids = $("#jqgTopMenu").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SortTopMenu","Admin")',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { ids: ids },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#jqgTopMenu').trigger("reloadGrid")
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("status: " + textStatus + " Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SortTopMenu(List<int> ids)
{
    return Json(_dataManager.TopMenu.Sort(ids));
}
```

**Manager DB method**

```
public bool Sort(List<int> ids)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
    {
        top_menu t = _dataContext.top_menu.FirstOrDefault(tm => tm.id == ids[i]);
        t.item_order = i;
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
    return true;
}
```